# Android: Can/How I get width of one view and assign it to another view using onPostCreate() method?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to set the width of a view based on the width of another view at run time.

I want to set the width in the `onCreate()` method,

```
 textView1.setWidth(textView2.getWidth());
```

Since the width of view is still not fully constructed, when above code is executed, getWidth() returns zero.

I attempted the same code in the `onPostCreate()` method, but the problem persists.

Output of the following is `0 , 0`.

```
protected void onPostCreate(BundlesavedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qwert);
    string = string + " , " + Integer.toString(textView.getWidth());
    Toast.makeText(this,string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

I thought `onPostCreate()` method will be called when all the views are completely rendered (inflated to their respective height and width).

Why is the `onPostCreate()` method **not behaving as expected**?

Comment: Because what you expect is not true. Keep searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnGlobalLayoutListener may give you what you need.

```
 View myView=findViewById(R.id.myView);
  myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //At this point the layout is complete and the 
                //dimensions of myView and any child views are known.
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, but then what is the work of      onPostCreate() method.

Comment: onPostCreate indicates that the execution of onCreate() just completed. But the layout inflation may not be finished.@vivekkumar

Comment: Is there any easy method like onPostCreate () , which is called only when layout inflation is completed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some delay before getting width of view.
you can get width by doing like this in onCreate()

```
  textView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            int viewWidth = textView.getWidth();
        }
    });
```